# Getting InvalidArgumentException for UpgradeStatusForm after installing the upgrade_status module on a Drupal 8 site

Tags: 8, upgrading

I have a very old install that began with 6 and is now at 8. I'm trying to get it updated to 9 but have gotten stuck with getting the upgrade_status module to work. After it was installed via composer, I get this error when navigating to the report:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

InvalidArgumentException: Class "\Drupal\upgrade_status\Form\UpgradeStatusForm" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ClassResolver->getInstanceFromDefinition() (line 24 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/ClassResolver.php).
```

I then tried to manually install it (very hacky) in the `/modules` directory to no effect.

I'm not sure if my install of Drupal is hopelessly broken and stuck at 8. I appreciate any suggestions or additional info that will help me troubleshoot it.

Thx,

Comment: _I then tried to manually install it_ Does that mean `composer require` didn't work?

Comment: I initially used `composer require drupal/upgrade_status` and after that it appeared in the reports page, but clicking on the link navigated to the above exception.

Comment: Did you install it and clear cache?

Comment: I just tried `composer clear-cache` (and also restarted Apache) but get the same error. However, the folders that are listed when clearing are in `~/.cache/composer/`. I also have a clean Drupal 9 site in a sibling directory to the Drupal 8 site. Could having these two on the same machine be an issue? Or could a mis-configuration cause them to stomp on each other in some way?

Comment: Hi, I guess Clive's question was: After you required `upgrade_status` with composer, did you install the module (from the admin interface or `drush en upgrade_status`) and did you clear the Drupal cache (from the admin interface or `drush cr`)? I don't think clearing composer cache will solve your issue.

Comment: @Clive && @misterdidi: The `drush cr` call did it! Having worked primarily with very old versions of Drupal I'm just getting comfortable with managing using `composer` and `drush`. I gave up a little too soon on this issue, so thanks so much for the patience.